# BizTalk 2010 Import Application triggers "Access to the path is denied" error

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have imported and stood up BizTalk 2010 installations and this is the first time I have encountered this error.  Googling and searching for this in StackOverflow did not uncover anything close to what I am seeing.

When I imported a BizTalk 2010 application (that was exported from another BizTalk server -- setting up a test BizTalk environment), the logs all appear to show that the import worked until near the end...

```
----8<---snip snip--->8----
Updating parties and enlistments...

PerformingEndChangeRequestsWithRollBack

* Performing EndTypeChangeRequest for resource type "System.BizTalk:Assembly".

* Performing EndTypeChangeRequest for resource type "System.BizTalk:BizTalkAssembly".

* Performing EndTypeChangeRequest for resource type "System.BizTalk:BizTalkBinding".

Import Wizard[10/4/2016 4:06:52 PM]: Error in Importing Application
Import Wizard[10/4/2016 4:06:52 PM]: Access to the path is denied.

Import Wizard[10/4/2016 4:06:52 PM]: Entering Page Results

The import process for the application xyzBiztalkApplication to the group BizTalk Group failed.

The following error(s) occurred.
-Access to the path is denied.
```

The log does not indicate to what path the access was denied.  One page that came the closest was this:  [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://biztalkintegrationblog.jnicolas.name/unable-import-configuration-file-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-path-denied/)

Event Viewer was also not helpful.  All it had was this:

```
Error while importing "C:\Users\BlarneyUser\Desktop\BiztalkInstall\xyzBizTalk_20161004.msi".
Access to the path is denied.
```

I already confirmed that BizTalk Adminstration Console was executed using "Run as Administrator" on a Windows 2012 Server, and that the user was added to the BizTalk Server Administrators group.

Finally, I whipped up a quick C# console application that probed every single folder in the C:\ drive to identify those folders that had UnauthorizedAccessException... and compared that to the other BizTalk server (from which I got the MSI) -- both were identical.

Any ideas on how to address that denied message?

Answer (score 0):

There is an article here [Access denied when deploying BizTalk solutions from Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikkole/2013/10/04/access-denied-when-deploying-biztalk-solutions-from-visual-studio/)

It sounds like you have done most of the relevant steps for a MSI rathter than Visual Studio in that article included.

> - Make sure your user account is member of BizTalk Server Administrators group and also member of SSO Administrators or SSO Affiliate Administrators group. These memberships should grant you required access to the database.

However one thing to try that the article also mentions is a utility from Microsoft called [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  That helps in identifying if something else has a lock on the files.  It is part of the [Windows Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-nz/sysinternals/bb545027.aspx) suite.

Comment: Thanks @dijkgraaf.  The user account is already a member of the BizTalk Server Administrators group and also a member of the SSO Administrators group.  I do not think it's a database issue, but rather a permissions issue -- as indicated by the error message.

As an aside, I went ahead and tried the exact same steps on a different server in that particular environment (a group of several servers), and the install and import both worked just fine.  It's specific to that one server.  Thanks for the help.  

I'll check out that Process Monitor if I can be given the green light to install it.